# How to get records of email and user information from outlook 2007 pst file?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a code that says that Instant of application is not created

when i excute this code this show output: This file "@"C:\Users\Toseef Abbasi\AppData \Local\Microsoft\Outlook" is not a valid outlook personal folder for file<.pst> Outlook failed to add personal store to this session

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace PSTReader
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main()
    {
        try

        {
            IEnumerable<MailItem> mailItems = readPst(@"C:\Users\Toseef Abbasi\AppData

             \Local\Microsoft\Outlook", "Outltoseefabbasi@hotmail.com-0000000b");

            foreach (MailItem mailItem in mailItems)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(mailItem.SenderName + " - " + mailItem.Subject);
            }

        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MailItem> readPst(string pstFilePath, string pstName)
    {
        List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();

        Application app = new Application();

        NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        // Add PST file (Outlook Data File) to Default Profile

        outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);

        MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName].GetRootFolder();

        // Traverse through all folders in the PST file

        // TODO: This is not recursive, refactor

        Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;

        foreach (Folder folder in subFolders)
        {
            Items items = folder.Items;

            foreach (object item in items)
            {
                if (item is MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;

                    mailItems.Add(mailItem);
                }
            }
        }
        // Remove PST file from Default Profile

        outlookNs.RemoveStore(rootFolder);

        return mailItems;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the question? What's not working?

Comment: Do you have Outlook 2007 installed on your system? Is it running when you run your code? You should also point out where in your code the exception occurs and describe what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Sorry wudzik and wudzik when i excute this code this show output: This file "@"C:\Users\Toseef Abbasi\AppData \Local\Microsoft\Outlook" is not a valid outlook personal folder for file<.pst> Outlook failed to add personal store to this session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the line below you point it to a folder and not the actual file.

```
IEnumerable<MailItem> mailItems = readPst(@"C:\Users\Toseef Abbasi\AppData

             \Local\Microsoft\Outlook", "Outltoseefabbasi@hotmail.com-0000000b");
```

shoud be like below where pstname.pst is the actual pst file.

```
IEnumerable<MailItem> mailItems = readPst(@"C:\Users\Toseef Abbasi\AppData

             \Local\Microsoft\Outlook\pstname.pst", "Outltoseefabbasi@hotmail.com-0000000b");
```

Comment: What is pstName? You already passes the pstFilePath in it, why do you need pstName?

Comment: @HoKy22 pstname is the actual name of the pst file.  Passing just the path doesnt tell the program which File it needs to open, its just a path to a directory.

Comment: In your case, the end of path is "pstname.pst", which is the pst file. Your pstname is "Outltoseefabbasi@hotmail.com-0000000b", which looks more like an email to me. How did you get this emailish thing?

Comment: you would have to ask the person who posted the question.